# Problem with Ubuntu 12.04 and Ideapad N581 (Broadcom)

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, broadcom, lenovo

I've installed Ubuntu 12.04 on a Lenovo Ideapad N581 and can't get the wifi to work reliably. I know it's a problem with the Broadcom drivers, but I still can't really work it out, I've tried a few things mentioned on other forums but none of them have worked yet (quite new to Linux).

Strangely enough, if I remove the battery for a few minutes, wifi works fine until the computer is shut down.

Here are the results of sudo iwconfig:

```
eth1      IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:"Pingu"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: F8:1A:67:CB:10:8E   
      Bit Rate=72 Mb/s   Tx-Power=200 dBm   
      Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Encryption key:off
      Power Management:on
      Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-36 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

eth2      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

sudo lsmod:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     32476  1 
snd_hda_codec_conexant    62363  1 
joydev                 17694  0 
rfcomm                 47562  12 
parport_pc             32867  0 
bnep                   18240  2 
ppdev                  17114  0 
coretemp               13642  0 
ghash_clmulni_intel    13221  0 
cryptd                 20531  1 ghash_clmulni_intel
rts5139               350620  0 
lib80211_crypt_tkip    17391  0 
uvcvideo               78117  0 
videobuf2_core         33025  1 uvcvideo
btusb                  22432  0 
wl                   3074942  0 
microcode              23030  0 
bluetooth             211860  24 rfcomm,bnep,btusb
videodev              125126  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core
videobuf2_vmalloc      12861  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       13405  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
snd_hda_intel          34063  3 
snd_hda_codec         135141  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_intel
alx                    73500  0 
snd_hwdep              17765  1 snd_hda_codec
mdio                   13808  1 alx
snd_pcm                97523  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
snd_seq_midi           13325  0 
snd_rawmidi            30750  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event     14900  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                61931  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_timer              29990  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         14498  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
snd                    83674  16 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
psmouse               102541  0 
serio_raw              13216  0 
cfg80211              208382  1 wl
lpc_ich                17145  0 
lib80211               14382  2 lib80211_crypt_tkip,wl
i915                  535221  3 
mei                    41410  0 
soundcore              15092  1 snd
snd_page_alloc         18573  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
drm_kms_helper         49259  1 i915
drm                   290595  4 i915,drm_kms_helper
i2c_algo_bit           13565  1 i915
ideapad_laptop         18235  0 
sparse_keymap          13891  1 ideapad_laptop
video                  19653  1 i915
mac_hid                13254  0 
lp                     17800  0 
parport                46563  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
ahci                   25869  2 
libahci                27338  1 ahci
```

and lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net

```
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Atheros Communications Inc. AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet [1969:1091] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3979]
    Kernel driver in use: alx
--
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:0587]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
```

**Update**

I removed and purged the *wl* drivers with `sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source`, shut the laptop down and removed the battery. On boot, no wireless drivers are loaded. The *brcmsmac* driver can be loaded with `sudo modprobe brcmsmac`. The country code is loaded with `sudo iw reg set DE`.

`lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` returns:

```
    02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:0587]
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
```

Right now, no networks are detected, but after these operations I was able to connect to a network (with a weak signal). After a few minutes, the connection dropped and could not connect again.

**13.04**

I booted from a live USB with 13.04. Networks are detected (but weak), `lspci` returns:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:0587]
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
```

`scan` returns:

```
wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: F8:1A:67:CB:10:8E
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=45/70  Signal level=-65 dBm  
                    Encryption key:off
                    ESSID:"Pingu"
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                          9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                Mode:Master
                Extra:tsf=0000000000f50a54
                Extra: Last beacon: 88ms ago
                IE: Unknown: 000550696E6775
                IE: Unknown: 010882848B960C121824
                IE: Unknown: 030101
                IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                IE: Unknown: 32043048606C
                IE: Unknown: 2D1AEF1103FFFF0000000000000000000000000000000406E6E70D00
                IE: Unknown: 331AEF1103FFFF0000000000000000000000000000000406E6E70D00
                IE: Unknown: 3D16010D0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: Unknown: 3416010D0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101870003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                IE: Unknown: DD0900037F01010000FF7F
                IE: Unknown: DD9E0050F204104A00011010440001011057000101103B0001031047001000000000000010000000F81A67CB108E1021000754502D4C494E4B10230009544C2D57523834314E10240003382E3010420003312E301054000800060050F204000110110019576972656C65737320526F7574657220544C2D57523834314E100800020086103C000101104900140024E26002000101600000020001600100020001
```

However, I can't connect to the network, with or without WPA2. I then install `linux-firmware-nonfree`, remove the drivers `brcmsmac` and `bcma`, reload `brcmsmac`. The wireless device is now `wlan1` instead of `wlan0`, it successfully scans but cannot connect (or when it does, it immediately drops). Wifi signals are still very weak. `iwconfig` during the 5 seconds or so that it successfully connects returns:

```
wlan2     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"Pingu"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: F8:1A:67:CB:10:8E   
          Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=19 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=42/70  Signal level=-68 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:4  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

This goes for both WPA2 and unsecured networks.

**12.04 Live**

When booting on 12.04 from a Live USB, wifi works when the proprietary SLA *wl* driver is loaded. `lspci` returns:
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN

```
Controller [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:0587]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: wl, bcma
```

Should I reinstall 12.04?

**backports 3.11**

After installing the backports 3.11 according to [Cannot connect to WiFi Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller (rev 01)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/339831/cannot-connect-to-wifi-with-ubuntu-13-04), the signal is still extremely low, I cannot connect to any network since I can't reliably detect any.
`iwconfig`:

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

`lspci -nnk`:

```
Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
Kernel modules: bcma
```

`sudo modprobe wl`:

```
FATAL: Module wl not found.
FATAL: Error running install command for wl
```

After installing `bcmwl-kernel-source_5.100.82`, I can detect networks but cannot join:
`iwconfig`:

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

`lspci-nnk`

```
Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
Kernel modules: bcma
```

`sudo modprobe wl`:

```
FATAL: Module wl not found.
FATAL: Error running install command for wl
```

Comment: Have you `sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer`?

Comment: I just did, from the starting point (so with wl driver in use), and it returns `firmware-b43-installer is already the newest version`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the proprietary STA driver *wl* is incorrect for your device 14e4:4727. Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Reboot. Post back and tell us if the wireless works better.

If signal strength is *still* low, try an earlier bcmwl-kernel-source as mentioned here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1110139/comments/42

```
wget http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_5.100.82.112+bdcom-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb
```

Or if yours is a 32-bit system:

```
wget http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_5.100.82.112+bdcom-0ubuntu3_i386.deb
```

Confirm 32- or 64-bit:

```
arch
```

Then do:

```
sudo dpkg -i bcmwl*.deb
```

Reboot and give us your report.

Comment: I did `sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source`, now I don't have any wireless networking at all.

Comment: Is the correct driver loading? lsmod | grep brcmsmac. If not, load it and tell us if it starts working: sudo modprobe brcmsmac

Comment: It did not load automatically, but after loading it I have this:
`brcmsmac              541775  0
mac80211              555272  1 brcmsmac
brcmutil               14756  1 brcmsmac
cfg80211              208382  2 brcmsmac,mac80211
cordic                 12575  1 brcmsmac
bcma                   35762  1 brcmsmac
` (sorry about the formatting).

Comment: When I load the brcmsmac driver, wireless seems to work a little, but I can only see networks in wifi channels 1-7 (and none in 8-13), and reception is much weaker than what it should be.

Comment: Please run: sudo iw reg get Is your country code listed? US? GB? etc.? If not, set it from here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 with this command: sudo iw reg set US or whatever. Now do all the channels appear?

Comment: I have to manually set the country code after each log in/log out, and when I do, the other channels appear, however still with a signal which is much much too weak. I also can't reliably connect to a wifi network (connects, connection drops, authentification required, finally does not connect at all).

Comment: Please do: gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local. Add one line above exit 0: iw reg set US  Proofread carefully, save and close gedit. Then please run and post: iwconfig.

Comment: iwconfig after adding the locale line in rc.local gives `wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=19 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
`

Comment: It would be far more helpful to see the iwconfig after you connected.

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense, my bad: `wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"Pingu"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: F8:1A:67:CB:10:8E   
          Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=19 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=42/70  Signal level=-68 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:3  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
` This is with the laptop less than 1 meter away from the router.

Comment: Getting this device to work properly in 12.04 is indeed challenging! I suggest you get a temporary wired ethernet connection and open a terminal and do: sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-cw-3.3-precise-generic  Reboot after detaching the ethernet.

Comment: Now there is no wireless connections at all, what module should I load? Would 12.10 or 13.04 be any better? I quickly tried a 13.04 live USB boot, but that didn't work straight out of the box.

Comment: Please try: sudo modprobe brcmsmac

Comment: iwconfig: `wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"Pingu"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: F8:1A:67:CB:10:8E   
          Bit Rate=43.3 Mb/s   Tx-Power=19 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=43/70  Signal level=-67 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:4  Invalid misc:44   Missed beacon:0
` Still a weak signal, but the connection hasn't dropped yet.

Comment: Super! Can you surf the web, email, etc.? Bit rate is greatly improved.

Comment: I could, but the connection dropped, and it can't connect again. I should also see more networks (neighbours), but it isn't the case...

Comment: Please try the live USB for 13.04. Be sure brcmwl-kernel-source is removed as above and sudo modprobe brcmsmac.

Comment: I've tried on 13.04 with the drivers wl and brcmsmac, none of which succeed in connecting to another network. With wl, the reception is better, while with brcmsmac, the reception is still quite bad (even after setting the right country code)... Any more ideas? Downgrading to 11.10?

Comment: Do you have 13.04 installed or from USB? Did you purge bcmwl-kernel source? You might also try sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree and then use brcmsmac.

Comment: 13.04 running from USB, so I can't reboot between operations. Just after startup, I have wireless connections possible, but no detected networks even after updating the country code. After that: purge bcmwl-kernel-source returns `package bcmwl-kernel-source not installed, so not removed`. Indeed, according to lspci, `Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge`. Nevertheless, I install the nonfree linux firmware, but that doesn't change anything.

Comment: After you install the firmware, sudo modprobe -r brcmsmac; sudo modprobe -r bcma; sudo modprobe brcmsmac and run iwconfig. Is there a wireless interface wlan0? Does it scan? sudo iwlist wlan0 scan

Comment: There is no wlan0, but there is a wlan1 interface. `scan` results in `wlan1     No scan results`.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure to have successfully installed the firmware, on which repository is it? Multiverse? How do I add that to apt-get?

Comment: Oops, forgot to update apt-get, `iwconfig` returns an wlan2 interface, and `scan` returns: `wlan2     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: 24:65:11:74:4D:AD
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=19/70  Signal level=-91 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
      ESSID:"FRITZ!Box 6360 Cable"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
Mode:Master
Extra:tsf=0000000f5aff2095
Extra: Last beacon: 14316ms ago`

Comment: ... `IE: Unknown: 0014465249
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B960C121824
                    IE: Unknown: 030101
                    IE: Unknown: 0706444520010D14
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
       Group Cipher : TKIP
       Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
      Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                  IE: Unknown: 32043048606C
                    IE: Unknown: 
             IE: Unknown: 0
                    IE: WPA Version 1
         Group Cipher : TKIP
           Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP`

Comment: Woo hoo! If it scans, it ought to connect for sure! Yes??

Comment: Sadly, no I can't: Networks are detected, but weakly, and connections are never successful. After a few minutes though, `scan` does not succeed anymore, and returns `No scan results`. I've tried it twice (removing the drivers, loading them again), with the same results.

Comment: @user187562 and Chili555, Please don't do extended discussions in the comments section.  Comments are just that, commenting on the post and not for troubleshooting. Instead of having to go back and forth in comments, consider editing your answer as it needs be. You can also avail the [chat] service available along with the site.

Comment: @user187562 I deeply regret I have no further suggestions. Sorry.

Comment: @user187562 we have new ideas about your device 14e4:4727. Please check here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/339831/cannot-connect-to-wifi-with-ubuntu-13-04 I will edit my answer to add the new information.

Comment: Did you install linux-headers-generic and build-essential? If not, do so and try again.

Comment: Yes, both are installed. Oups, my bad (again), I entered deconfig instead of defconfig... trying it right now.

Comment: The backports successfully installed, but no wireless networks were detected. I also installed the `bcmwl-kernel-source_5.100.82.112` but still no signal. Should I shut down, remove the battery and wait 10min?

Comment: Does the module load cleanly? sudo modprobe wl Is a wireless interface created? iwconfig