# Cannot connect to WiFi Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller (rev 01)

Tags: wireless

I just installed Ubuntu 13.04 with my Pavilion dv6. My laptop originally was operated under Windows 7. My WiFi worked fine when it was still on Windows 7. However, after I changed the OS to Linux using Ubuntu 13.04, the WiFi stopped working anymore. I can see the network list. I can also use wired network, and it is fine. I just cannot connect to my router even with the correct password.

Technical:

```
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 06)
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller (rev 01)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5209 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
03:00.1 SD Host controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5209 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please get a temporary wired ethernet connection, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo -i
apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
echo brcmsmac >> /etc/modules
exit
```

Detach the ethernet, reboot and tell us if it is working.

If you suffer poor signal strength, a well documented bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/856314; I suggest you try the brcmsmac driver backported from kernel version 3.11. Obtain a temporary wired ethernet connection, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic
```

Download this file to your desktop: https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v3.11-rc3/backports-3.11-rc3-1.tar.bz2  Right-click it and select 'Extract Here.' Now back to the terminal:

```
cd Desktop/backports-3.11-rc3-1
make defconfig-wifi
make
sudo make install
```

You may get a comment about a private key. Unless it is mentioned as an error, it may safely be ignored. Reboot and let us know the result.

If signal strength is *still* low, try an earlier bcmwl-kernel-source as mentioned here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1110139/comments/42

```
wget http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_5.100.82.112+bdcom-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb
```

Or if yours is a 32-bit system:

```
wget http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_5.100.82.112+bdcom-0ubuntu3_i386.deb
```

Confirm 32- or 64-bit:

```
arch
```

Then do:

```
sudo dpkg -i bcmwl*.deb
```

Reboot and give us your report.

Comment: Yes, it works now. The problem right now is that the signal is very weak even though my laptop is just right next to the router. Is there any way that i can fix the connection? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you join me in a chat room? http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10386/intel I am there now.

Comment: it requires me to have 20 reputation and i am just have 6. sorry.

Comment: I am editing my answer to suggest a next step.

Comment: although "private key" was mentioned, no error was reported. However, the signal still is weak after rebooting.

Comment: See new edit, please.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The problem is solved. I can connect to my wifi now